# Show that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}(n+m)}\leq \frac{\pi}{\sqrt{m}}$

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, summation, upper-lower-bounds

Let $m\in\mathbb{N}^*$. Show that $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}(n+m)}\leq \dfrac{\pi}{\sqrt{m}}$$

A hint is given by the problem: *You could find this using an integration*

**How did I try to use the hint:**

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}(n+m)}\leq \int_0^\infty\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}(x+m)}dx$$

If it's correct, I found this as a primitive function:

$2\sqrt m \arctan\left(\dfrac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{m}}\right)$, that has the good limit as $x\rightarrow +\infty$.

Is that correct?

Comment: "A hint is given... I don't know how to start." Well, did you try using the hint?

Comment: Yes, but I can't find the function to integrate that gives $\pi$. Do you have any guess?

Comment: Why would you search for a function that integrates to $\pi$? Have you even tried directly integrating the given summand?

Comment: The lower limit on the integral should be $0.$

Comment: "Is that correct?" No, the integral should be over $x\in(0,\infty)$ (or replace the upper bound with $N$ if you wish.)

Comment: $2\sqrt m \arctan\left(\dfrac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{m}}\right)$ is not correct. Revisit your change of variable $x=??$ and then $dx={??}'$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** do you know any numerical methods for estimating an integral as a sum in some way?  Can you cast the left hand side of your inequality as an approximation to an integral and then evaluate that integral?

Comment: Possibly too vague? Hopefully not, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt I'd rather give a hint that's too vague than one that gives too much away.  I think that between your comments and the hint given in the problem, OP should have enough to go away and solve this.